# Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pen, RectangleF)

Tags: .net, graphics, drawing, overloading, rectangles

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawrectangle.aspx

FillRectangle, DrawRectangle, FillElipse and DrawEllipse all can take 4 Float (or "Single") parameters: x, y, width, height. DrawRectangle is the only one that will not take a RectangleF, though.

I was wondering if anyone knew why this is. It sure seems like they just plain forgot to overload it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well it sure does look like an omission to me too.

Interestingly, there is an overload of DrawRectangles that takes a RectangleF[] array as a parameter.

So I suppose you could use this with an array size of one if needed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Andy's answer the extension should be as below

```
public static class GraphicsExtensions
{
    public static void DrawRectangle(this Graphics g, Pen pen, RectangleF rect)
    {
        g.DrawRectangles(pen, new[] { rect });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but just for a reference: I believe the correct way is to use either [round](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.round?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [truncate](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.truncate?view=netframework-4.7.2), such as:

```
Dim BBox As RectangleF = ListOfRectangleF(3)         ' get RectangleF any way you have it
Dim p As New Pen(Brushes.DarkRed)
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, Rectangle.Round(ptBBox)) ' draw RectangleF using Rectangle.Round()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Andy's answer, this simple extension method makes life easier.

```
using System.Drawing;

public static class GraphicsExtensions
{
    public static void DrawRectangle(this Graphics g, Pen pen, RectangleF rect) =>
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height);
}
```